# How to move other elements on jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple jQuery website, where there are four blocks, when you press a block, another block slides out of it. It all works, for the most part, however, i was wondering how i could get the block that slides out to move the other elements below it down.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var height = 145;
  var speed = 600;
  $("#one").animate({
    width: "100%",
    height: height
  }, speed, function() {
    $("#two").animate({
      width: "100%",
      height: height
    }, speed, function() {
      $("#three").animate({
        width: "100%",
        height: height
      }, speed, function() {
        $("#four").animate({
          width: "100%",
          height: height
        }, speed);
      });
    });
  });

  $("#one").click(function() {
    $(".dropDown").not("#oneS").slideUp();
    $("#oneS").slideToggle();

  });

  $("#two").click(function() {
    $(".dropDown").not("#twoS").slideUp();
    $("#twoS").slideToggle();
  });

  $("#three").click(function() {
    $(".dropDown").not("#threeS").slideUp();
    $("#threeS").slideToggle();
  });

  $("#four").click(function() {
    $(".dropDown").not("#fourS").slideUp();
    $("#fourS").slideToggle();
  });


});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 .selectors {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
#one {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#two {
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#three {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#four {
  background-color: green;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100px;
}
.dropDown {
  background-color: #E9E9E9;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  //overflow:auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#oneS {
  display: none;
  top: 150px;
}
#twoS {
  display: none;
  top: 150px;
}
#threeS {
  display: none;
  top: 150px;
}
#fourS {
  display: none;
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="one" class="selectors">
    <div id="oneS" class="dropDown"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="two" class="selectors">
    <div id="twoS" class="dropDown"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="three" class="selectors">
    <div id="threeS" class="dropDown"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="four" class="selectors">
    <div id="fourS" class="dropDown"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Four blocks:
[image: Four Blocks]

Slid out block:
[image: Slid out block]

As you can see when the block is slid out, it covers over the red and yellow block. Instead i would like the sliding block to move the red and yellow block down the page, and out from under the sliding block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things wrong.

The general issue is that you're fighting the natural behavior of the HTML since the `.dropDown` elements are children of the `.selectors` elements. You would get closer to your desired result if they were siblings.

Make them siblings and remove some troublesome CSS properties like `position:absolute` and `top` and you should get closer to your desired effect.

Here is a JSBin of a working demo: http://jsbin.com/titibununu/1/edit?html,css,js,output